# Problema consumir web service en android studio

Tags: java, android, webservice

Buenos días tengo una consulta: Resulta que tengo el siguiente código para consumir un webservices desde android studio:

```
        String responce = null;

        final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempurl.org";
        final String URL=Globales.conexionAP.toString();
        final String METHOD_NAME = "Afectacion";
       final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempurl.org/Afectacion"; 


        PropertyInfo pvcppc = new PropertyInfo();
        PropertyInfo pvcnumero = new PropertyInfo();
        PropertyInfo pvcfecha = new PropertyInfo();
        PropertyInfo pvcmonto = new PropertyInfo();
        PropertyInfo pvctarifa = new PropertyInfo();
        PropertyInfo pvcuser = new PropertyInfo();
        PropertyInfo pvcpass = new PropertyInfo();


        pvcppc.setName("ppc");
        pvcppc.setValue(vppc.toString());

        pvcnumero.setName("numero");
        pvcnumero.setValue(vnumero.toString());

        pvcfecha.setName("fecha");
        pvcfecha.setValue(vfecha.toString());

        pvcmonto.setName("monto");
        pvcmonto.setValue(vmonto.toString());

        pvctarifa.setName("tarifa");
        pvctarifa.setValue(vtarifa.toString());

        pvcuser.setName("user");
        pvcuser.setValue(Globales.conexionAPUsuario.toString());

        pvcpass.setName("pass");
        pvcpass.setValue(Globales.conexionAPClave.toString());

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,  METHOD_NAME);


        request.addProperty(pvcppc);
        request.addProperty(pvcnumero);
        request.addProperty(pvcfecha);
        request.addProperty(pvcmonto);
        request.addProperty(pvctarifa);
        request.addProperty(pvcuser);
        request.addProperty(pvcpass);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER10);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive LoginResult;
            LoginResult = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();//AQUI ESTA EL PROBLEMA


            System.out.println("=================Register User Results: "+LoginResult.toString());
            //System.out.println(LoginResult.toString());
            responce = LoginResult.toString();
            String resultfinal= responce.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Pero el webservices tiene estas etiquetas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esas etiquetas de recibo y creds (los que marque con rojo) no puedo enviarle los datos al webservices ya que no los encuentra y me da error, me podrian ayudar porfa cual seria la manera correcta de enviar esos datos al webservices, muchas gracias de antemano.

Lo que me esta dando estos problemas son los contenedores ese de recibo y creds no me reconoce a la hora de enviar los datos.

Comment: Según la estructura que muestras, tendrías que crear un objeto `PropertyInfo` para `recibo` y anidar en ella `ppc, numero, fecha` etc y crear un objeto `PropertyInfo` para `creds` y anidar en ella `user` y `pass` ... no hay mayor misterio, simplemente producir la estructura que el WS está esperando.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si es que ahi es donde tengo la duda ( porque nunca lo habia hecho de esa forma) como le agrego los datos a esa propiedad ya que son varios he buscado pero no veo ejemplos, muchas gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Me parece que [este ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14958872/5587982) puede servirte.